# How can I build on the result of old expectations in a feature spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Let's say I'm testing how to create a Widget:

```
feature "widget management" do
  scenario "creating a widget_1" do
    visit root_url
    click_link "New Widget"

    fill_in "Name", with: "Awesome Widget"
    click_button "Create Widget"

    expect(page).to have_text("Widget was successfully created.")
  end
end
```

Okay, great, but let's say I want to create another widget, and test how those two interact with each other. In a unit test I would have no trouble stubbing or using factory girl's `create` method to set up the hashes I need, but with a feature integration test, I want to test the whole application realistically, just to really, really make absolutely sure there are no bugs. I don't want to stub or use a create method, I want to literally create two different widgets using the form found at the root_url!

But if I do this:

```
feature "widget management" do
  scenario "creating a widget_1" do
    visit root_url
    click_link "New Widget"

    fill_in "Name", with: "Awesome Widget"
    click_button "Create Widget"

    expect(page).to have_text("Widget was successfully created.")
  end

  scenario "creating a widget_2" do
    visit root_url
    click_link "New Widget"

    fill_in "Name", with: "Awesome Widget_2"
    click_button "Create Widget"

    expect(page).to have_text("Widget_2 was successfully created.")
  end
end
```

Awesome Widget_2 is created in the database, but Awesome_Widget, from the last scenario, is no longer in the database. This is because my `config.use_transactional_fixtures` is set to true. I want the test database to be cleaned between expectations, though, at least in all of my unit specs, as they use contexts to set up the database in a certain way before each expectation.

But I don't want the database to be cleaned between each scenario in my extensive integration spec! I want to build on what's happened before. Is this the correct way to do it? Or should I keep transitional_fixtures and be stubbing/creating in a before block for all of my feature specs?

Maybe then create one long expectation that creates multiple widgets and makes them interact with each other in one huge `it` block?

I just want to get to emulate true behaviour! I want to go through the forms, make thousands of widgets (using a loop and a factory girl sequence) and watch it all work for peace of mind, (maybe using a headed server such as Selenium for extra certainty) before it goes live! Surely that's a sensible thing to want to do? It's been surprisingly tricky to do this!

I can understand stubbing in a request spec, because though you're testing a faculty of your app that uses controllers, models, views and active record, you're testing that feature of your app in isolation.

With a feature spec though, you're meant to be telling a story. A user (or whatever) does this, and then he does that, meanwhile, another user is created, he "friends" the first user, the first user "accepts" and so on. Don't really know how I can do this if the database is wiping itself between each expectation!

**Basically, how can I turn transactional_fixtures off for certain specs, but have them on for other specs, and is this advisable?**

Up for using database cleaner instead of transactional_fixtures!

## **Update**

Okay, this seems to be a good setup for telling a 'story' with a feature spec:
(Note, I've only included the code relevant to setting this up, your spec_helper needs a few more things in it to get rspec, factory girl, guard, whatever working)

**Gemfile**

(adding the database_cleaner gem for better control when dropping tables)

```
gem 'database_cleaner'
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

(configuring the database_cleaner to drop all tables in the test database, also setting transitional fixtures to true so that all tables are dropped between expectations(this is overwritten in the feature spec itself using an instance method, which you'll see in a bit))

```
RSpec.configure do |config| 
  config.after(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  I18n.enforce_available_locales = true   
  config.order = "random"
end
```

**spec/features/integration.rb**

And finally, the feature spec that builds on old expectations to 'tell a story'. Note the instance method that overrides the spec_helper's configuration regarding transactional fixtures:

```
feature "widget management" do
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  scenario "creating a widget_1" do
    visit root_url
    click_link "New Widget"

    fill_in "Name", with: "Awesome Widget"
    click_button "Create Widget"

    expect(page).to have_text("Widget was successfully created.")
  end

  scenario "creating a widget_2" do
    visit root_url
    click_link "New Widget"

    fill_in "Name", with: "Awesome Widget_2"
    click_button "Create Widget" # Both exist in the database and so they can take part in the story!

    expect(page).to have_text("Widget_2 was successfully created.")
  end
end
```

I suppose the question has changed a little!

## ***What are your thoughts on the above as a way to write feature specs?***

By the way, if you're attempting this, or anything that uses database cleaner to manually remove information from your database, be aware you can get in a little mess if you're using active record (which you should be in an integration spec) and model validations! Basically, if data from the last spec is lingering in your database for some reason (if you've just turned transactional_fixtures off, for example), your specs could fail any uniqueness validations you have set up, because identical data is already exists in the database.

If you have database cleaner setup like above, it's set to clean the database when the suite finishes. Because your spec is hitting a validation error, it's never finishing, so database cleaner never cleans the database. And because the database hasn't been cleaned, when you run the spec again, your spec hits the validation error again, it still doesn't finish and data base cleaner still doesn't clean the database and so on into infinitum.

**To cut a long story short, if you're getting validation errors, manually clean your tables.**

You can do this with the sqlite3 shell (A little easier than rails console I think, but you can use that as well if you want. It's similar commands with any shell, postgres, mysql, whatever):

In the command line:

```
$ cd db
$ sqlite3 test.sqlite3
sqlite > DELETE FROM widgets;
```

*You may need to run that command a few times to empty different tables depending on your spec. The syntax of the command: DELETE FROM [table name you wish to delete from];*

```
sqlite > .exit
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment to clarify that `database_cleaner` has gotten better for the issue that you experienced. You can see a code sample here: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example

Answer (score 2):

> What are your thoughts on the above as a way to write feature specs?

I don't think it's a good idea to share data between scenarios. A scenario shouldn't rely on data from another scenario. This will cause problems if you randomize the execution order in your `RSpec` configuration.

Another problem that I see is that you are not really testing different scenarios.

```
feature "widget management" do
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  scenario "creating a widget_1" do
    visit root_url
    click_link "New Widget"

    fill_in "Name", with: "Awesome Widget"
    click_button "Create Widget"

    expect(page).to have_text("Widget was successfully created.")
  end

  scenario "creating a widget_2" do
    visit root_url
    click_link "New Widget"

    fill_in "Name", with: "Awesome Widget_2"
    click_button "Create Widget" # Both exist in the database and so they can take part in the story!

    expect(page).to have_text("Widget_2 was successfully created.")
  end
end
```

The only difference between the two scenarios is that you are varying the name but not in a relevant way.

You could improve this suite by varying the type of input (e.g. valid then invalid) in order to test more paths in your code. I would refactor that suite to look more like this:

```
describe "widget management" do
  before do
    visit root_url
    click_link "New Widget"

    fill_in "Name", with: name
    click_button "Create Widget"
  end

  context "when creating a widget with a valid name" do
    let(:name) { "Awesome Widget" }

    it "returns a success message" do
      expect(page).to have_text("Widget was successfully created.")
    end
  end

  context "when trying to create a widget with an invalid name" do
    let(:name) { "" }

    it "returns an error message" do
      expect(page).to have_text("Widget_2 must have a valid name.")
    end
  end
end
```